# Why won't variabes from other methods return to the main method? (more inside)

Tags: java, oop, scope, quadratic

The purpose of this program is to print 
the number of solutions and the solution(s) to a quadratic function, 
entered by the user.

The problems here is that I get errors for having private variables, 
why is this? Also for my constructor it states that my variables cannot be resolved even though 
they are established in the main method. Finally, my variables will pass to the main method or to the "toString" method for use 
in the main method.

This is for a school assignment and my professor requires that I use the "toString" method as well as have private variables. I apologize in advance for any formatting mistakes and for the large question, for I am new
 to this site.

```
import java.util.Scanner

public class QuadraticSolver
{
    private static Scanner in;

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {   
        QuadraticSolver qs = new QuadraticSolver();
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        private double a;
        private double b;
        private double c;

        System.out.println("Enter coefficients for quadratic function. ");
        a = in.nextDouble();
        b = in.nextDouble();
        c = in.nextDouble();

        qs.getRoot1(a,b,c);
        qs.getRoot2(a,b,c);
        qs.numOfSolutions(a,b,c);

        System.out.println("Your quadratic function is " + a + "x^2 + " + b + "x + " + c);
        System.out.println(qs.toString());
    }

    public QuadraticSolver()
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = 0;
    }

    public double getRoot1(double a,double b,double c)
    {
        private double root1;   

        root1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2) - 4*a*c)) / (2*a);
        return root1;
    }

    public double getRoot2(double a,double b,double c)
    {   
        private double root2;

        root2 = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2) - 4*a*c)) / (2*a);
        return root2;
    }

    public int numOfSolutions(double a,double b,double c)
    {
        private int sol = 0;
        private double d;

        d = Math.pow(b,2) - 4*a*c;

        if(d > 0)
        {
            sol = 2;
        }
        else if(d == 0)
        {
            sol = 1;
        }
        else if(d < 0)
        {   
            sol = 0;
        }

        return sol;
    }

    public String toString() 
    {
        return "There are(is) " + sol + " solution(s). x = " + root1 + " x = " + root2;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to have `getRoot1` and `getRoot2` return different values.

Comment: Doesn't this give a compile error? If so, please show the error message you got.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 a cannot be resolved to a variable
 b cannot be resolved to a variable
 c cannot be resolved to a variable
 sol cannot be resolved to a variable
 root1 cannot be resolved to a variable
 root2 cannot be resolved to a variable

 at QuadraticSolver.<init>(QuadraticSolver.java:44)
 at QuadraticSolver.main(QuadraticSolver.java:23)

Comment: Andrew: this information is too important to be buried in comments. I recommend that you place the information that you've posted above into your main question by [editing the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32555801/edit), and also indicate which line is line 23. Also for future questions, always tell us of any and all compilation errors or exceptions, posting the full information with your question. It's just too important to leave out.

Comment: My mistake, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should move the variables to the class level:

```
public class QuadraticSolver {

    private double a;
    private double b;
    private double c;

    ...

}
```

Next, you need to access the variables that belong to the object `qs`:

```
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {   
        QuadraticSolver qs = new QuadraticSolver();
        in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter coefficients for quadratic function. ");
        qs.a = in.nextDouble();
        qs.b = in.nextDouble();
        qs.c = in.nextDouble();

        ...
    }
```

And finally, you should remove the variables from the methods `getRoot1()`, etc. This is because each method can access the variables `a`,`b`,`c` belonging to the object itself. Thus:

```
    public double getRoot1()
    {
        double root1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2) - 4*a*c)) / (2*a);
        return root1;
    }
```

And at the call sites:

```
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        ...
        double root1 = qs.getRoot1();
        double root2 = qs.getRoot2();
        int numsol = qs.numOfSolutions();
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Private *instance variables* belong to a class.  When you create an object that is an instance of a class, the object may have instance variables that belong to the object; if you create multiple instances of a class, each of those instances (objects) has its own set of instance variables.  You declare those in the class:

```
public class QuadraticSolver
{
    private static Scanner in;
    private double a;  // instance variables
    private double b;
    private double c;
```

Now, to access those variables, you need to have an object.  If you're in a non-static method inside the class, or in a constructor for the class, the method will work with an object called `this`, so you could say `this.a` or just `a` to get at that variable.  If you're outside the class, or in a *static* method in the class (including `main`), you need to tell it what object you're working with.  In your program, your `main` method has an object `qs` that is a `QuadraticSolver`, and you can get at that object's instance variables by saying `qs.a`, `qs.b`, etc.

Variables declared inside a method are *local* variables.  They're for use only within that method.  They don't declare instance variables for an object.  You can't use the keyword `private` on them, because that keyword is only for instance variables (and other things that aren't variables).  You can't use the variables outside that method.  If you declare them in an inner set of curly braces, you can't use them outside the curly braces.  If you declare a local variable that's the same name as an instance variable, there's no connection between the two.